# When does the sum of a convergent sequence minus its limit converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence that converges to $L$ and let $\{b_n\}$ be a sequence defined as
$$b_n := \sum_{k=1}^{n}(a_k-L).$$
Perhaps this is a vague question, but what restrictions do we have to place on $\{a_n\}$ in order for $\{b_n\}$ to converge? Or, more to the point, what are some nontrivial (i.e. $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ coverges) conditions that $\{a_n\}$ can satisfy so that $\{b_n\}$ converges?

Comment: This depends on how fast $a_n$ converges to $L$.

Comment: A "convergent sequence minus its limit" is just a "sequence converging to zero". The question is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Define $c_n=a_n-L$.  Now $b_n=\sum_{k=1}^nc_k$ and your usual rules for a series converging apply.  If $|c_n| \lt \frac j{n^{1+\epsilon}}$ for $\epsilon \gt 0$ it converges.  The alternating series theorem applies, and so on.

Comment: Is the "$j$" supposed to be there?

Comment: @HiMatt:  yes, it is just any numeric constant.  $c$ was already taken